# How to add such loading effect to my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add the effect of loading the results of the search, which can look like this:

[image]

To my jQuery code:

```
$('#popup-search-input').on('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
          $('.search-results').html('searching');
          $.get('/api/entity-product-search/' + $(this).val(), function (data) {
            $('.search-results').html(data);
          });
        }
      });
```

I'm not using ajax here because it does Drupal behaviors.

Comment: That's an Animated GIF. If you want to show it, use `$.ajax()` instead of `$.get()`, and it has option to execute callback on `beforesend`, so you could reveal the GIF that way and then hide it once complete in `success` callback. If you want more help, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You have the code ready, just replace **$('.search-results').html('searching');** with **$('.search-results').html('<img src='path-to-file/animated-gif'>');** and on success, that will be replaced with the returned data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add it to the search input itself you can use an image or icon and position it over the input.

```css
.search {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.search input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search .fa {
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="search">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Searching...">
  <!-- using Font Awesome library for icon -->
  <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you looking for, when you get success from $.get preloader will be hide again

```js
$('#popup-search-input').on('keypress', function (e) {
  
        if (e.which === 13) {
        $("#preloader").show();
          $('.search-results').html('searching');
          $.get('/api/entity-product-search/' + $(this).val(), function (data) {
          $("#preloader").hide();
            $('.search-results').html(data);
          });
        }
      });
```

```css
#preloader{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="popup-search-input" type="text"/>
<img id="preloader" src="https://i.gifer.com/origin/c0/c0bf6e330c9d364e65b6549271806932_w200.gif">
```